# can't install libboost-python in debian

Tags: debian, package-management, dpkg, aptitude

I think something is wrong the package manager I use this command to install `libboost-python`

```
sudo aptitude install libboost-python1.62.0
```

I get the following error that later suggests removing python3.7!

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.7 : Breaks: libboost-python1.62.0 (< 1.62.0+dfsg-6) but 1.62.0+dfsg-4 is to be installed
```

Output of `apt policy`:

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=9.8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=non-free,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/contrib amd64 Packages
     release v=9.8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=contrib,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
     release v=9.8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=stretch-updates,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=9,o=Debian,a=stable,n=stretch,l=Debian-Security,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
     release v=9.8,o=Debian,a=stable,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ftp.us.debian.org
Pinned packages:
```

Output of `dpkg -l | grep libboost-python` gives back nothing. So what is that error message saying?

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the output of `apt policy`? I’m guessing you’re running Debian 9 with a newer version of Python...

Comment: @StephenKitt Done. and yes, I have Debian 9 and both Python v2.7.13 and Python v3.7.

Comment: @muhzi did you manually install these packages or did you alter your `sources.list` to install the newer versions of python from testing or unstable?